# Emacs ^m end of line encoding

Tags: windows, emacs

I was wodnering why my emacs started putting ^m at the end of every line, i know how to "fix it" but i was wondering what caused it to happen. I have been using emacs in windows for some time now and it started more recently. Does anyone know why this starts?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the reason is that the buffer is using '...-unix' coding system when the file contains Windows carriage-return/linefeed line ends.  The mode line will show you the coding system in use.  See ['Coding Systems'](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Coding-Systems.html#Coding-Systems) in the Emacs Manual.

```
Ctrl-h C
```

will display the coding system currently in use.

Comment: ahh i see what causes it but is there something that i could of done to make this start happening?

Comment: You may understand, but if you don't give us information about what you are discovering, it is hard to help.  What did you find?

Comment: sorry, i meant to say i see what you were saying, not what the actual cause of the problem is.

Comment: @Shantanu IMO your 2nd comment also doesn't help in any way to diagnose your problem

Answer (score 1):

I see this happening when the file contains both `\r\n` and `\n\r` line endings. That is, someone has written broken Windows line endings to the file (`\n\r`).

Go through your file and look for lines that **start** with `^M`. This implies that the carriage return was after the newline character on the previous line, which is incorrect.

If that is the case, go back to the program that generated the file and make sure that it's writing correct Windows line endings.